# itertools groupby not grouping unicode string

Tags: python

as seen below, Why is my groupby failing to group the `message bubbles and fonts`key?

```
>>> d
[{'id': 99, 'title': u'bubble 2', 'price': 4, 'product_class': u'message bubbles and fonts', 'categories': [], 'image': '/media/uploads/card/d7fab7c2-6796-41bb-aa3e-5378f799c0ed.jpg', 'thumbnail': '/media/uploads/card/d7fab7c2-6796-41bb-aa3e-5378f799c0ed.100x100.jpg'}, 
{'id': 98, 'title': u'roundish product 1', 'price': 4, 'product_class': u'roundish', 'categories': [], 'image': '/media/uploads/card/b74311b1-3944-4330-9a82-612a71452b2c.jpg', 'thumbnail': '/media/uploads/card/b74311b1-3944-4330-9a82-612a71452b2c.100x100.jpg'}, 
{'id': 97, 'title': u'bubble 1', 'price': 4, 'product_class': u'message bubbles and fonts', 'categories': [], 'image': '/media/uploads/card/9d508746-6ba8-467a-add5-115fe410da2c.jpg', 'thumbnail': '/media/uploads/card/9d508746-6ba8-467a-add5-115fe410da2c.100x100.jpg'}, 
{'id': 96, 'title': u'accessory product 3', 'price': 4, 'product_class': u'designer accessories', 'categories': [{'name': u'playful'}], 'image': '/media/uploads/card/c20d81c1-2dc9-4252-bb93-e340b2c911da.jpg', 'thumbnail': '/media/uploads/card/c20d81c1-2dc9-4252-bb93-e340b2c911da.100x100.jpg'}, 
{'id': 95, 'title': u'accessory product 2', 'price': 4, 'product_class': u'designer accessories', 'categories': [{'name': u'serious'}], 'image': '/media/uploads/card/aa51229b-07ed-47d1-bf3b-4d1af17bff7f.jpg', 'thumbnail': '/media/uploads/card/aa51229b-07ed-47d1-bf3b-4d1af17bff7f.100x100.jpg'}, 
{'id': 94, 'title': u'accessory product 1', 'price': 4, 'product_class': u'designer accessories', 'categories': [{'name': u'playful'}], 'image': '/media/uploads/card/249f4771-777f-4b28-bdc2-987be9a8a2d4.jpg', 'thumbnail': '/media/uploads/card/249f4771-777f-4b28-bdc2-987be9a8a2d4.100x100.jpg'}, 
{'id': 93, 'title': u'string product 2', 'price': 4, 'product_class': u'stringish', 'categories': [{'name': u'funky'}], 'image': '/media/uploads/card/21f9cfd1-4dd7-4752-9b1b-ec40cf87f4e0.jpg', 'thumbnail': '/media/uploads/card/21f9cfd1-4dd7-4752-9b1b-ec40cf87f4e0.100x100.jpg'}, 
{'id': 92, 'title': u'string product 1', 'price': 4, 'product_class': u'stringish', 'categories': [{'name': u'nylon'}], 'image': '/media/uploads/card/f593d9ae-20f8-4d53-86a7-62568d6b5f10.jpg', 'thumbnail': '/media/uploads/card/f593d9ae-20f8-4d53-86a7-62568d6b5f10.100x100.jpg'}, {'id': 89, 'title': u'card completed with ornaments', 'price': None, 'product_class': u'Card', 'categories': [], 'image': '', 'thumbnail': ''}, 
{'id': 77, 'title': u'Specification by Example', 'price': None, 'product_class': u'Book', 'categories': [{'name': u'Essential programming'}, {'name': u'Essential programming'}], 'image': '', 'thumbnail': ''}, 
{'id': 74, 'title': u'Genetic Programming', 'price': None, 'product_class': u'Book', 'categories': [{'name': u'Essential programming'}, {'name': u'Essential programming'}], 'image': '', 'thumbnail': ''}, 
{'id': 14, 'title': u'Artificial Intelligence', 'price': None, 'product_class': u'Book', 'categories': [{'name': u'Essential programming'}, {'name': u'Essential programming'}], 'image': '', 'thumbnail': ''}]
    >>> a = groupby(d, key= lambda x: x['product_class'])
    >>> for k,v in a:
    ...     print k
    ... 
    message bubbles and fonts
    roundish
    message bubbles and fonts
    designer accessories
    stringish
    Card
    Book
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> `itertools.groupby(iterable[, key])`
>
> Make an iterator that returns
> consecutive keys and groups from the iterable. The key is a function
> computing a key value for each element. If not specified or is None,
> key defaults to an identity function and returns the element
> unchanged. **Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the
> same key function.**